# Spring boot not loading log4j2.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j2, spring-aop

I'm trying to add log4j2 framework inside my spring boot application, and I'm using spring AOP to isolate logging concern apart from my logic business.
Unfortunately when I try to log my messages, log4j2 doesn't work and it uses the spring default logging instead.

This is my  Logging aspect class where I try to log messages: LoggingAspect.java

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    @Around("com.obs.dqsc.api.config.AspectConfig.businessService() || com.obs.dqsc.api.config.AspectConfig.repositoryOperations()")
    public Object logMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
            throws Throwable {
        final Class<?> targetClass = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(targetClass);

        try {
            final String className = targetClass.getSimpleName();
            logger.debug(getPreMessage(joinPoint, className));

            final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();

            final Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
            stopWatch.stop();

            logger.debug(getPostMessage(joinPoint, className, stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()));

            return retVal;
        } catch (final Throwable ex) {
            logger.error(getErrorMessage(ex), ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private static String getPreMessage(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final String className) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder()
                .append("Entered in ").append(className).append(".")
                .append(joinPoint.getSignature().getName())
                .append("(");
        appendTo(builder, joinPoint);
        return builder
                .append(")")
                .toString();
    }

    private static String getPostMessage(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final String className, final long millis) {
        return "Exit from " + className + "." +
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName() +
                "(..); Execution time: " +
                millis +
                " ms;";
    }

    private static String getErrorMessage(final Throwable ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }

    private static void appendTo(final StringBuilder builder, final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        final Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                builder.append(", ");
            }
            builder.append(args[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.obs.dqsc</groupId>
    <artifactId>dqsc-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Finally this is my log4j2.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %-50c{1.} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And also when I try to use logger.info() instead of logger.debug() it prints something in the console, but with .debug() it does not! (the message was printed using spring default logging apparently)

> my application.properties does not contain anything related to log4j,
> and also my log4j2.xml is inside src/main/resources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

exclude spring boot default logging this way:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and add spring boot log4j2 dependency like you already do and you´ll be fine.
Cause you excluded the logging module only on the web module it still gets pulled in by other dependencies like the data mongodb module for example.

Comment: oh I see it now, this helped my day, thank you so much!